# How can I integrate fitVids.js into a .load function?

Tags: ajax, video, load

I'm new to jquery and I need to integrate a bit of code and I'm calling it from an external html file with the .load() function. That part of code it's a .div containing a video and a description. All I need to do is to make fitVids work on the code loaded from the external file.

This is the html loaded in the div.featured-container:

```
<div class="featured-container">
    <div class="container player clearfix">
            <div class="span8 video-container">
                <iframe width="600" height="338" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QkhqI49QeaM?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="span4 featured-content">
                <div class="feat-meta">May 8, 2010 at 16:50 / by <a href="">Silviu Stefu</a></div>
                <h2>Retiner - Mobile UI Kit</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse.
                </p>
                <a class="button-normal" href="">Read More...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
    //load the first list item link
    var firstLoad = $('.thumbnails li:nth-child(2) a').attr('href')+' .player';
    $('.featured-container').load(firstLoad,'',showTheContent());
    function showTheContent() {  
            $('.player').fitVids().fadeIn('slow');  
        }

    //load the links on click
    $('.thumbnails li a').click(function(){
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' .player';
        $('.player').fadeOut('slow',loadContent);  
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#load').fadeIn('normal'); 
        function loadContent() {  
            $('.featured-container').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());
        }  
        function showNewContent() {  
            $('.player').fadeIn('slow',hideLoader());  
        }  
        function hideLoader() {  
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');  
        }
        return false; 
    });
```

So, where I should put the .fitVids() function to make the fideo fluid?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the success function for this, so that if its loaded run the code.

```
$("#success").load("file.html", function(response, status, xhr) {
   if (status == "succes") {
   // your code
  }
});
```